# Reading xml data from remote server securely

Tags: php, xml, curl, remote-access

I need to get some xml data from my customer's server. I created two php files for doing this.
When I call a php file in my server (reader.php), it calls the file in remote server (client.php) and gets data via curl.
Of course, everyone can access this client.php file, so I created some validations for security. The reader.php calls client.php with some special parameters (send with POST) and client.php checks these parameters, if everyting is fine, prints the xml data for reading.

I wonder this approach is enough for security? This XML data is really important and I don't want to do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you MUST use SSL for secure transmission of information.

Second of all, what are these "special parameters" you refer to? If you are talking about a username/hashed password, then in conjunction with SSL encryption you are doing what 95% of websites do for security. Of course, you can always get more extreme.

Comment: I use SSL and reader.php file works in my server. But there isn't SSL in the remote server I am trying to get data
These "special parameters" contain a encypted password and two private keys.

Comment: @Orçunyumarcı: When you request `client.php` that request must be under SSL as well.